# ClassNotFoundException thrown when trying to find jdbc driver using Vaadin Framework

Tags: java, mysql

I am making a web app with java, using the Vaadin framework. I have tried to implement jdbc, but gotten an error. I have downloaded the latest jdbc jar.
The code throws a ClassNotFound exception.

I have tried to add it to eclipse build path, and I have tried to put it into WEB-INF/lib (C:\Users\desktopname\Documents\Java-ee\target\my-starter-project-1.0-SNAPSHOT\WEB-INF\lib
I have also tried to put it into

```java
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class DBConnect {

    private Connection con;
    private Statement st;
    private ResultSet rs;

    public DBConnect() {
        try {
            //com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
            con= DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://remotemysql.com:3306/Z3EoHAi3pW", "username", "password");
            st = con.createStatement();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error:" + e);
        }
    }

}
```

Error:java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add mysql JDBC driver jar file to your classpath. Then you will be fine. You can download [here](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/). If you are using maven. use below:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.6</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Maven, add the below in pom.xml file.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>8.0.16</version>
</dependency>
```

If you are not using maven, then download the mysql-connector jar file from the below location and put it inside WEB-INF/lib.

http://central.maven.org/maven2/mysql/mysql-connector-java/8.0.16/mysql-connector-java-8.0.16.jar